# Angular enabling/disabling modules and features upon server response

Tags: angular, server, module, permissions

Is there a common way to make some modules and features in Angular app available on server's response? For example when I pay I get access to that module or a feature. Also I'm interested in partial availability i.e. user with read-only status unable to write or delete some data.

Answer (score 0):

For modules you have guards. In essence https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate. Unability to write / delete etc doesn't have a single default implementation. There are libraries out there, but frankly it's not a hard directive to create.